# The joint pdf of the amount X of almonds and amount Y of cashews in a 1-lb can of nuts

Tags: statistics

The joint pdf of the amount $X$ of almonds and amount $Y$ of cashews in a 1-lb can of nuts was:

$f(x, y) = \begin{cases} 24xy & 0 \leq x \leq 1,\, 0 \leq y \leq 1,\, x + y \leq 1\\ 0 &  \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

1. Obtain the marginal pdf of the amount $X$ of almonds in a 1-lb can.
2. What is the expected amount $E(X)$ of almonds?

Answer (score 0):

1. By definition, we define the marginal pdf of $X$ by 
   $$p_X(x) = \int_y f(x,y)\,dy$$
   You're given that $$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}24xy & 0\leq x\leq 1,\, 0\leq y \leq 1,\, 0\leq x+y\leq 1\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
   and thus we have that
   $$p_X(x) = \int_?^?24xy\,dy$$
   What are the appropriate limits of integration?  I'll leave that to you to figure out.
2. By definition, 
   $$E[X] = \int_x xp_X(x)\,dx$$
   Thus, you can only answer this part once you've done the first part.